# How to auto-populate cells in browse progress when exiting a cell

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

example:

I have a browse with the columns "Code item", "Item description". When placing the apos fill the code of the item automatically fills the cell with the description of the item of a temp-table.

Anyone know how I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to auto-fill the description column after the user enters something in the code column? You can do that using an `ON LEAVE` trigger on the browser. Here is an example that copies the code column to the description column when the user leaves the code. You can also use `ON VALUE-CHANGED` to update the description as the user types the code.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttBrs NO-UNDO
    FIELD Code AS CHARACTER
    FIELD Descr AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE QUERY qBrs FOR ttBrs SCROLLING.

DEFINE BROWSE brs1
    QUERY qBrs DISPLAY
        ttBrs.Code COLUMN-LABEL "Code Item"
        ttBrs.Descr COLUMN-LABEL "Item Description"
        ENABLE ttBrs.Code ttBrs.Descr
    WITH NO-ROW-MARKERS SEPARATORS SIZE 80 BY 10 FONT 4 FIT-LAST-COLUMN.

ON LEAVE OF ttBrs.Code IN BROWSE brs1
DO:
    ttBrs.Descr:SCREEN-VALUE IN BROWSE brs1 = ttBrs.Code:SCREEN-VALUE.
END.

DEFINE FRAME fFrame
    brs1 AT ROW 1 COL 1
    WITH VIEW-AS DIALOG-BOX SCROLLABLE.

CREATE ttBrs.

VIEW FRAME fFrame.
OPEN QUERY qBrs FOR EACH ttBrs.
brs1:SENSITIVE = TRUE.

WAIT-FOR "GO" OF FRAME fFrame.
```

Comment: Perfect! tkv TheDrooper